# Adding compilation flags to Qt to use mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I am using ubuntu to build a project that uses mysql. To compile the project from the command line I use the following flags:

```
$(mysql_config --cflags)$(mysql_config --libs)
```

However, when I am trying to build from Qt, I get that undefined reference to mysql_close and the rest of mysql connection functions.

I tried adding the representation of the previous command line flags to QMAKe in Qt and still same errors.

Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the output of "mysql_config --cflags" to the compiler flags with:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS += $$system(mysql_config --cflags)
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $$system(mysql_config --cflags)
```

Likewise for LIBS:

```
LIBS += $$system(mysql_config --libs)
```

All of the above goes into your project file (*.pro) of course.

Answer (score 0):

To include Qt's SQL modules, you need this

`QT += sql`

in your `.pro` file.  You also need to make sure the drivers have been compiled, and put into the plugins folder, `libqsqlmysql.so` in

> ~/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/plugins/sqldrivers

in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql is not included in the SQL modules by default so Matt Philip's solution won't work.

What you need to do is install the mysql dev package by doing

> sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

and then add it to the pro file like this

> LIB += -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient

This worked for me on ubuntu

Comment: @opcOde already have libmysqlclient-dev install and tried to add the libraries as you mentioned yet didn't work. Complaining, undefined reference to mysql_close, _query....

Comment: @Syntax_Error that means the library is not linked properly try -lmysql flag instead of -lmysqlclient